# How do I compare dates in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following situation:

I have a certain function that runs a loop and does stuff, and error conditions may make it exit that loop.
I want to be able to check whether the loop is still running or not.

For this, i'm doing, for each loop run:

```
LastTimeIDidTheLoop = new Date();
```

And in another function, which runs through SetInterval every 30 seconds, I want to do basically this:

```
if (LastTimeIDidTheLoop is more than 30 seconds ago) {
  alert("oops");
}
```

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about:

```
newDate = new Date()
newDate.setSeconds(newDate.getSeconds()-30);
if (newDate > LastTimeIDidTheLoop) {
  alert("oops");
}
```

Comment: That just concatenates 30 onto the end, such as "Sun Dec 07 2008 16:45:19 GMT-0500 (EST)30"

Comment: Yes, you are right!
I have corrected it, with an amended version.

Answer (score 7):

JS date objects store milliseconds internally, subtracting them from each other works as expected:

```
var diffSeconds = (new Date() - LastTimeIDidTheLoop) / 1000; 
if (diffSeconds > 30)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var dateDiff = function(fromdate, todate) {
    var diff = todate - fromdate;
    return Math.floor(diff/1000);
}
```

then:

```
if (dateDiff(fromdate, todate) > 30){
    alert("oops");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a date object and use setSeconds().

```
controlDate = new Date();
controlDate.setSeconds(controlDate.getSeconds() + 30);

if (LastTimeIDidTheLoop > controlDate) {
...
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it just sets the time to 30 seconds, like "1:15:30"

You want to add 30 seconds, you do controlDate.setSeconds(controlDate.getSeconds() + 30);